# Keyboard not working after running SDL2 based program

Tags: sdl

I'm now developing a mini game, using SDL. When I use SDL1.2, the keyboard input event signal is well-caught.

However, if I use SDL2.0, the keyboard input event signal doesn't seem to be caught.

Also, even if I exit the program somehow(ex. set 10s and terminate) now the keyboard doesn't work at all.

Is it a bug in SDL2?

Comment: I just now ran into this same issue. I guess it's time to pay a visit to the SDL bug tracker.

Comment: Hi. Same problem. There is any update?